# Problems using ShanWan usb wireless controller Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: usb

First of all, I want to say that the controller works perfectly in my RaspberryPi.

My problem within Ubuntu is that the left analog joystick and the D-pad map the same (both as Axis 0 (L+R) and Axis 1 (U+D).  My right analog and XYAB buttons map all as Buttons 0,1,2,3 (U,R,D,L).

I have tried the "how to" on the sixaxis help forum which mostly applies to Bluetooth controllers, but even so, when I run the sixpair file it tells me that there are no usb controllers listed.

`dmesg` shows the following for controller:

```
[75728.800480] usb 6-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[75732.114366] usb 6-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[75732.300867] usb 6-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0575
[75732.300875] usb 6-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[75732.300880] usb 6-2: Product: PC/PS3/Android
[75732.300884] usb 6-2: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[75732.309010] input: ShanWan PC/PS3/Android as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:2563:0575.0008/input/input23
[75732.309345] hid-generic 0003:2563:0575.0008: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Gamepad [ShanWan PC/PS3/Android] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input0
[77365.652250] input: ShanWan PC/PS3/Android as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:2563:0575.0009/input/input24
[77365.712607] hid-generic 0003:2563:0575.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Gamepad [ShanWan PC/PS3/Android] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input0
[77365.712653] usb 6-2: authorized to connect
```

Any suggestions? I am an Ubuntu newbie, be gentle!

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the <kbd>home</kbd> button on the controller to light up two of the red LEDs seams to fix it for me. You can press it again to revert to previous behavior.